# HTML hyperlinks not working via Cloudflare Pages

Tags: html

When I run the HTML file directly and when I host it locally the links go to the website I put, but for some reason when I host the code using CF Pages the link will display "https://example.com/google.com/"

Here's the code:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_top"><img border="0" src="example.gif" width="169" height="105"></a>
```

Again when I host it locally the links will show "https://www.google.com".

Is this like some weird setting on CF Pages or did I mess something up?

Comment: Could it be the `target=_top` which is causing the problem? Why are you using it?

Comment: If you want the link to open in a new page, use target="_blank" instead of _top

Comment: Tried removing "target=_top" as well as adding "target=_blank" and neither solved the issue. They worked when I hosted it on my system but when I published on CF Pages I still have the same issue where it links to "https://example.com/google.com/".

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Right before I gave up on this I realized that I put https:/google.com instead of https://google.com lmao.

Still not sure why it actually went to the websites when I hosted on my PC but whatever.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).